# Imported image get artifacts after shading

Tags: shaders

I try to make a leaf (png with no background) in shading with a use of Translucent.

Unfortunately, when I use *Fac* in *Mix Shader* or connect color to *Fac* socket of the *Mix Shader*, I get strange artifacts (leaf on the left).

How to remove these artifacts?

[image: How I want it to look]

[image: but how it looks when I connect two]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: Hello. You should multiply your color with the alpha before plugging it into the Mix Shader, it looks like there is color information where the alpha is 0 in your input texture. Alternatively use a mix shader with a transparent BSDF and alpha as a factor at the end of your node tree